# Age restricted variable product woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store that has a variable product "Season passes". This product has different age categories (variations - adult, teen, junior etc.) to determine price. When a customer checks out i have a field where they would enter their birthdate. I need the birthdate entered to match the the age category selected and stop the customer from proceeding if it does not. Any help please?

Comment: Without any code in your question, you will have very poor chances to get helped… Actually, your question is just unclear and too vague…

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Comment: Also the logic behind your process is flawed.  A customer making a purchase may not be the same customer using the product.  Example:  I am an adult, but I would buy a season pass for my kid.  Therefore the product is a junior season pass, but the birthday entered is mine.  Also, asking people their birth date on a checkout form is going to discourage purchases.